# Add column of repeating sequence of sequential numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, tibble

I would like to add a column repeating the numbers 1 to 577 to a dataframe of over 15,000 rows.

This is the dataframe:

```
> head(corr_dat_cond1)
  participant search_difficulty key_resp.corr key_resp.rt target_position distractor1_colour
1        1010         difficult             1   1.0820000            left      [0.82,0.31,0]
2        1010         no_search             1   0.5400000            left         [-1,-1,-1]
3        1010         difficult             1   0.5119998            down      [0.82,0,0.31]
4        1010         no_search             1   0.7079999           right         [-1,-1,-1]
5        1010         difficult             1   1.0249999              up      [0.82,0.31,0]
6        1010         no_search             1   0.4889998            left         [-1,-1,-1]
  distractor2_colour non_target_colour non_target_pos cue_uposition target_char non_target_char cue_time
1      [0.82,0,0.31]     [0.82,0.31,0]      [0.328,0]            up           =               x      1.1
2         [-1,-1,-1]        [-1,-1,-1]      [0.328,0]         right           x               =      1.2
3      [0.82,0.31,0]     [0.82,0,0.31]      [0.328,0]          down           x               =      1.0
4         [-1,-1,-1]        [-1,-1,-1]      [0,0.328]          left           =               x      1.4
5      [0.82,0,0.31]     [0.82,0.31,0]     [0,-0.328]          left           x               =      1.4
6         [-1,-1,-1]        [-1,-1,-1]     [0,-0.328]            up           x               =      1.0
            cue_colour   n cue_validity       mrt     stdev low_cutoff high_cutoff cond trial_num
1 Mismatch (Onset) cue 577        FALSE 0.7639095 0.2481090  0.0195825   1.5082365    1         1
2 Mismatch (Onset) cue 577        FALSE 0.5530880 0.1243826  0.1799402   0.9262358    1         2
3 Mismatch (Onset) cue 577         TRUE 0.7639095 0.2481090  0.0195825   1.5082365    1         3
4    Match (Color) cue 577        FALSE 0.5530880 0.1243826  0.1799402   0.9262358    1         4
5    Match (Color) cue 577        FALSE 0.7639095 0.2481090  0.0195825   1.5082365    1         5
6 Mismatch (Onset) cue 577        FALSE 0.5530880 0.1243826  0.1799402   0.9262358    1         6
```

The trial_num column is my initial attempt at trying adding a column of sequential numbers. This is the code I used:

```
corr_dat_cond1$trial_num <- 1:nrow(corr_dat_cond1)
```

However, I'd like the numbers to **repeat every 577 rows instead of counting all the way up to the number of rows** in the dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try `rep(1:577, length.out = nrow(corr_dat_cond1))`

Comment: Use "group_by()" in advance of the giving ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rep_len` function.

```
trial_num <- rep_len(1:577, nrow(corr_dat_cond1))
```

This is the same as calling `rep` with the `length.out` specified.